# representing $\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin x}{x^3}}dx$ in terms of $\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, infinity

representing $$I_1=\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin x}{x^3}}dx$$ in terms of  $$I_2=\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}}dx$$

I used $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$ and put the value of $\sin^3(x)$ in $I_2$ got
$$I_2 = \int_0^\infty{\frac{3\sin(x)-\sin(3x)}{4x^3}}dx$$
$$I_2 = \int_0^\infty{\frac{3\sin(x)}{4x^3}}dx - \int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin(3x)}{4x^3}}dx$$
Now I replaced $x$ with $x/3$ in second integral:
$$I_2 = \int_0^\infty{\frac{3\sin(x)}{4x^3}}dx - \int_0^\infty{\frac{9\sin(x)}{4x^3}}dx$$
This gives that $$I_2=\frac{-3}{2}\int_0^\infty{\frac{\sin x}{x^3}}dx$$

But according to Wolfram alpha LHS converges but RHS diverges.
Can anyone point out where am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^3}dx$ had some finite value your technique would imply $I_2$ is some multiple of it, but since it doesn't you're basically "computing" $\infty-\infty$, [an indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).

Comment: @J.G. But how can it be that LHS = finite and RHS=infinite. I think it's $\infty-0$form

Comment: No it's not. What you've done is assume $aX-bX=(a-b)X$ works for divergent $X$.

Comment: your LHS converges to $\frac{3 \pi}{8}$ and your RHS converges to $\frac{- \pi}{4}$

Comment: refering to the derivation; $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{sin^n}{x^m} dx  = \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n-m}{2} \pi}}{2^n (m-1)!}$ $\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n-m}{2}]} (-1)^k  nc_k (n-2k)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

$I_{1}$ does not exist (in Lebesgue sense nor improper sense: $\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{3}}dx$).
The reason is that when $x$ is small, $\sin x\approx x$. However,
$\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}=+\infty$.